# Visual Basic equivalent of ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize()

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, .net-6.0

Since .NET 6 microsoft introduced a [new application bootstrap code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/whats-new/net60?view=netdesktop-6.0#new-application-bootstrap) for Windows Forms applications:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

While the provided code examples are in C#, attempting to use them in my Visual Basic application leads to an error, specifically mentioning that ApplicationConfiguration is not defined.

How should this be adapted for Visual Basic?

Comment: The Application Framework takes care of that. Check your `Application.Designer.vb`

Comment: The classes and methods are the same no matter the language. If you get an error saying the type is missing, it's because a `using` directive is missing. The reason examples are in C# is because developers overwhelmingly prefer C#. Microsoft provided similar documentation and examples for both languages for over 15 years but in the end stopped putting resources into documentation or examples people weren't interested in

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos An error they're finally making up for with Copilot that can translate all those C# examples to VB.net. Some day I may forgive them, until they start charging me for the privilege.

Comment: It is specific to C#, an auto-generated class whose path is C:\Users\hpass\AppData\Local\Temp\.vsdbgsrc\07f226dc43e06f65e2ca9bdfb758c30c4dd6330a\ApplicationConfiguration.g.cs on my machine.  Same kind of approach as the vb.net IDE takes to have options in the Project > Properties tabs affect the way the program works.  But vb.net doesn't have these specific goodies, it is in maintenance mode.

Answer (score 0):

The VB *Windows Forms App* project template in VS2022 generates an `ApplicationEvents` class in which you can handle the `ApplyApplicationDefaults` event to set your application defaults which is what `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize()` does for C# WinForms projects.